# How to create entities related to themselves, magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, magento-1, flat, entities

I sent this question some days ago:

"I'm using the module Ultimate Module Creator to create new entities and relate them to products, categories and between them.

But I don't know how to relate the entities to themselves. I can't do it with the module. How I could create this type of relation without the module? "

Answer (score 0):

And I've solved it with Ultimate Module Creator:

1# I've created the entity called Looks that I want to relate with itself

2# To relate an entity wit itself, I only need a table with two columns (look_id, linked_look_id). So, I've created other entity called Related, and Looks is parent of Related. Therefore, I have the first column (look_id) in the table. Then, I've created other attribute called linked_look_id. Type: dropdown, to select the look. And now comes the trick!! I've selected Source: Manually defined, and I've assigned it any  values.And now comes the trick!! I've selected Source: Manually defined, and I've assigned it any  values. But then I've modified the code (see step3)
[image]

3# I've modified the file Namespace/Looks/Model/Related/Attribute/**Source/Linkedlookid.php** and now the function getAllOptions return the values of the entity Looks.

```
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false)
{
      if (is_null($this->_options)) {
          $this->_options = Mage::getResourceModel('namespace_looks/look_collection')

          ->load()
          ->toOptionArray();
      }
      $options = $this->_options;
      if ($withEmpty) {
          array_unshift($options, array('value'=>'', 'label'=>''));
      }
      return $options;

}
```

[image]

Now in the form, I can select the one look and related look.

I hope it helps